# d3.js dynamic Tooltip for Chord diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I am looking for a way to create a tooltip which changes its value based on the section the mouse is hovering over.

For example: When mouseover "A", the tooltip displays "1". When mouseover "B", the tooltip displays "2".

So far I have implemented a tooltip which appends a fixed string. But this will show the same string for all sections.

I have used the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        font: 14px sans - serif;
    }

    .chord path {
        fill - opacity: .70;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: .3px;
    }

    div.tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 60px;
        height: 12px;
        padding: 8px;
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background: #ddd;
        border: solid 1px #aaa;
        border - radius: 3px;
        pointer - events: none;
    }
</style>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">


        d3.tsv('Intercompany.csv', function(err, data) {
            // Loading Intercompany.csv into matrix
            var matrix = [],
                companies = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);

            data.forEach(function(row) {
                var mrow = [];
                companies.forEach(function(c) {
                    mrow.push(Number(row[c]));
                });
                matrix.push(mrow);
            });


            var chord = d3.layout.chord()
                .padding(0.05)
                .sortGroups(d3.descending)
                .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
                .sortChords(d3.descending)
                .matrix(matrix);


            var width = 1000,
                height = 600,
                innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * 0.35,
                outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.06;

            var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"])
                .range(["#4D689F", "#81BC00", "#00A1DE", "#72C7E7", "#3C8A2E", "#BDD203", "#DDDDDD", "#BCBCBC", "#9A9A9A", "#575757", "#313131", "#002776"]);


            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

            var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 1e-6);



            function mouseover() {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", 1);
            }

            function mousemove() {
                div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+15 + "px")
                    .style("top", d3.event.pageY-30 + "px")
                    .style("opacity", 1)
                    .text("example");
            }

            function mouseout() {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
           }


            var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
                .data(chord.groups)
                .enter().append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "group");

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);

            g.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return fill(d.index);
                })
                .style("stroke", function(d) {
                    return fill(d.index);
                })
                .attr("id", function(d, i) {
                    return "group-" + d.index
                })
                .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                .on("mouseout", mouseout);

            /*    g.append("svg:text")
                    .attr("x", 6)
                    .attr("class", "companie")
                    .attr("dy", 12)
                    .filter(function(d) { return d.value> 25; })
                  .append("svg:textPath")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#group-" + d.index; })
                    .text(function(d) { return companies[d.index]; });
            */

            var config = {
                rotation: 0,
                textgap: 35
            };

            var offset = Math.PI * config.rotation,
                width = config.width,
                height = config.height,
                textgap = config.textgap
            colors = config.colors;

            g.append("svg:text")
                .each(function(d) {
                    d.angle = ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2) + offset;
                })
                .attr("dy", ".50em")
                .style("font-weight", "bold")
                .style("font-size", "12px")
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null;
                })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + (outerRadius + textgap) + ")" + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return companies[d.index];
                })
                .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                .on("mouseout", mouseout);

            function groupTicks(d) {
                var k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / d.value;
                return d3.range(0, d.value, 10).map(function(v, i) {
                    return {
                        angle: v * k + d.startAngle,
                        label: i % 5 != 0 ? null : v / 10 + "m"
                    };
                });
            }

            var ticks = g.selectAll("g")
                .data(groupTicks)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + outerRadius + ",0)";
                });

            ticks.append("line")
                .attr("x1", 1)
                .attr("y1", 0)
                .attr("x2", 5)
                .attr("y2", 0)
                .style("stroke", "#000");

            ticks.append("text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("font-size", "9px")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    // Beschriftung drehen wenn Kreiswinkel> 180°
                    return d.angle > Math.PI ?
                        "rotate(180)translate(-16)" : null;
                })
                .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.label;
                });

            function chordColor(d) {
                return fill(d.source.value > d.target.value ?
                    d.source.index : d.target.index);
            }

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "chord")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(chord.chords)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius))
                .style("fill", chordColor)
                .style("opacity", 1);


            function fade(opacity) {
                return function(g, i) {
                    svg.selectAll(".chord path")
                        .filter(function(d) {
                            return d.source.index != i &&
                                d.target.index != i;
                        })
                        .transition()
                        .style("opacity", opacity);
                };
            }
            g.on("mouseover", fade(0.1))
                .on("mouseout", fade(1));

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Put it on JSFiddle so I can play with the code :)

Comment: All you have to do is pass data to the mousemove so mousemove(d){} and then the text would be text(d);

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
        function mousemove(d) {
            var output = "";
            var company = companies[d.index];
            switch (company) {
                    case "A": output = "1";
                    break;}

            div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+15 + "px")
                .style("top", d3.event.pageY-30 + "px")
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .text(output);
        }
```